# How to change the name of a PDF file in Crystal Reports?

Tags: pdf, crystal-reports

We have crystal report which generates an invoice for our clients, crystal report's  name is invoice.rpt.  When crystal report is created and print to PDF file, the default pdf file name is `invoice.pdf`.

is there a way to change the pdf name to the invoice number (which is a variable inside crystal report)?

for example, we open `inovice.rpt` to create a invoice `10000`, can we print to pdf file and name set to `1000` by default, instead of `invoice.pdf`?

Answer (score 0):

No such option with Crystal alone.

But several 3rd-party tools provide that functionality. See [Ken Hamady's excellent web site](https://kenhamady.com/bookmarks.html) for lists and reviews of 3rd-party Crystal Reports tools.

Answer (score 0):

Just change to name of CrystalReportViewerID as desired

**CrystalReportViewerID="SaleReport-16Nov2019"** in code

Answer (score -2):

ReportClientDocument objReportClientDocument = new ReportClientDocument();
objReportClientDocument.open("WEB-INF\reports\Folder/report.rpt", 0);

IReportSource       objIReportSource        = objReportClientDocument.getReportSource();
ReportExportControl objReportExportControl  = new ReportExportControl();
objReportExportControl.setReportSource(objIReportSource);

objReportExportControl.setName("Report_FileName");